# How to exchange data and files between two devices by NFC using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, nfc

I am a flutter developer, I want to make an application to exchange messages and files by using NFC technique
I used nfc_in_flutter plugin for reading and writing NFC tags but I don't know how to send and receive data and files between devices by using NFC in flutter.
Could any one help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

Generally you don't try and send data between 2 devices using NFC, there is a standard for it, but most devices don't support it (it has never been supported on iOS and Android has dropped support for it as it was unreliable)

Use Bluetooth or Wifi Direct instead.

**Update:**
If you have to use NFC then the `nfc_in_flutter` plugin is no use, you are going to have to call native code for each platform yourself / write your own plugin.

And for 2 iOS devices, then forget it, just not possible because of what the OS supports.

When one device is an Android there is a complicated method that some people have had some success with but it still has it's issue.

The Android device does Host Card Emulation (HCE) and pretends to be a really Type 4 NFC tag, then other devices can read/write to it as if it were a real Tag which both iOS and Android Support. BUT on older Android devices then the deprecated Android Beam might get in the way and you would need to use `enableReaderMode` to do the read/write on Android.

You will need to put in a lot of error handle in the read/write App as NFC comms is very slow and very prone to loosing the connection, so it would have to handle loosing the connection and restarting where it last successful read from/written to.

All these problems make this extremely difficult to achieve a workable solution and was the main reason Google removed Android Beam for Android to Android sharing (which does use a NFC peer to peer protocol)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I know that, but I have to use nfc

Comment: Note - I am not an Android developer, but I got interested in the ability to send a short dynamically generated data record (a NDEF would suffice). The Android NFC docs (the page got updated less than 2 months ago) still mention Beam - https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc

It is unclear if an iOS device can receive the payload, though.

Comment: That page also mentions "These APIs have since been deprecated, but are available to support older devices". Since Android 10 it has not been available to use (It was too unreliable to use and was recommend to use Bluetooth or wifi direct instead or Google Nearby instead). This actually uses a NFC Forum standard method that iOS has never supported